# Node.js: Redirect .profiler() and .logging() output

Tags: node.js, express

IS there a way I can get the output of the .profiler() and .logging()? Right now, it is printing in the console, I'd like to get that on file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [winston logging module](https://github.com/indexzero/winston) for logging to files.